# select_set() method of Listbox tkinter widget in Python enables multiple selections even selectionmode is set to BROWSE

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am working with Python 3.10.5 64bit and a strange behavior regarding the listboy widget of the tkinter modul.

Look at the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cities = ['New York', 'Beijing', 'Cairo', 'Mumbai', 'Mexico']
list_source = tk.StringVar(value=cities)

lst_cities = tk.Listbox(
    master=root,
    listvariable=list_source,
    height=6,
    selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
    exportselection=False) # enables that the selected item will be highlighted

lst_cities.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)

lst_cities.select_set(0)
lst_cities.select_set(1)
lst_cities.select_set(2)

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see I have created a simple listbox and finally used the 'select_set' method several times with different indexes. I would assume as I have set selectmode to SINGLE that a new 'select_set' call would remove the previous selection, but this isn't the case so I ended with 3 selected entries. Is this a desired behavior? If so it looks like an inconsistent behavior.

I tried to clear the selection with:
`
lst_cities.selection_clear(tk.END)
lst_cities.select_clear(tk.END)

but this doesn't seem to have any effect. So I am also looking for way to clear the selection,
so I can select a new entry. Seems I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

According to the help on `selection_set()`:

```
selection_set(self, first, last=None)
    Set the selection from FIRST to LAST (included) without
    changing the currently selected elements.
```

currently selected elements are not affected.

So you need to clear current selections using `selection_clear()` (or `select_clear()`):

```py
selection_clear(0, "end")
```

Better to use a function to simplify it:

```py
def select_set(idx):
    lst_cities.selection_clear(0, "end")
    lst_cities.selection_set(idx)

selection_set(0)
selection_set(1)
selection_set(2)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I noticed that I used selection_clear() in the wrong way and missed the first '0' parameter.

Comment: @KlausSobel If my answer has solved your problem, consider to accept it as the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this. As you saying that **several times with different indexes** by using `tk.MULTIPLE` is good choice instead of `tk.SINGLE`. There are several ways to do.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

cities = ['New York', 'Beijing', 'Cairo', 'Mumbai', 'Mexico']

def remove_item():
    selected_checkboxs = lst_cities.curselection()

    for selected_checkbox in selected_checkboxs[::-1]:
        lst_cities.delete(selected_checkbox)

lst_cities = tk.Listbox(root,
                        selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE,
                        exportselection=False,
                        height=6)
lst_cities.pack()

for item in cities:
    lst_cities.insert(tk.END, item)

tk.Button(root, text="delete", command=remove_item).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Result MULTIPLE:

[image]

Result after delete:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will add this to my sample library and eventually enhance my listbox base class with, but so far I only use a single select in my listboxes

Comment: You can use SINGLE, but cannot selected multiple.